# How to download all IPA files that already deleted from AppStore?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

I am still wondering if there's a big archive of all and old IPA files that was on AppStore long years ago.
Because most of 32bit games is deleted from AppStore after iOS 10-11 release.

I saved some of them from my purchases sections, but not all of them is available for download from there. I don't understand why.

Isn't it possible to "catch" Apple server link, where it stores all IPA versions of games for certain iOS versions? It would be great, because current ways to install older version of apps (or deleted apps even) are so difficult.

That's sad, because there are ton of various iOS games that lost forever due to Apple strict applications rules etc, due to 64bit games later.

I don't have many apps in my purchases list, and of course I can extract them, but I can't decrypt them, I don't understand how to do it, to share it with anyone. Thanks!

P.S.
Some games included inapp purchases. Because of games being so, so old, now server doesn't work at all, and you can't buy anything, because server not responding, and Apple server too.
I don't know also, how to bypass it to unlock content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a big archive containing all historic IPA files.

I don't buy fully into your argument that Apple's actions are the reason why tons of games are lost forever. The Apple Store is just a distribution method. It is not so that Apple requires app developers to delete their own copies of these apps.

If the developers of those games were actually interested in keeping them archived and publicly available for the sake of future generations, they can just do so.

Comment: So, it isn’t possible to catch the direct link of downloading IPA of version you need from Apple server? It can be possible only from purchases section, and only for latest supported iOS version, not earlier.

Comment: Downloading an app from the App Store does not work like downloading a DMG file from a more "old fashioned" third party Mac software developer distributing a simple application from their web site. There you would be used to downloading a single file or package, and that everyone downloads the same bits, and every time it is downloaded it is the same. This is not the case for app downloads.

Comment: That's really sad :( Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: I wouldn't call it sad. It is great for many with lower capacity phones.